# How to validate a data field with exclude_if in Laravel?

Tags: laravel, laravel-validation

I want to validate **thumbnail** field. When user upload the file with mime type is pdf the thumbnail is required. then, if user upload the photo which mime type is not pdf. thumnail field is not required.

Here is the code I have tried:

```
  'file' => 'required|mimes:jpg,jpeg,pdf|max:2048',
  'thumbnail' => 'exclude_if:file,mimes:pdf|required'
```

I know that the validate on **thumbnail** was not correct. Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So you basically require thumbnail if mime type is pdf , you can use required_if validation.
First add

```
use Illuminate\Validation\Rule;
```

Then,

```
Validator::make($request->all(), [
     'file' => 'required|mimes:jpg,jpeg,pdf|max:2048',
     'thumbnail' => Rule::requiredIf(function () use ($request) {
          if ($request->file->getMimeType() == 'application/pdf') {
                 return true;
           } else return false;
      }),
]);
```

Comment: [mime_content_type](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mime-content-type.php) is a php function.

Comment: Thank @bhucho I'll check it.

Comment: I got this issue: message": "mime_content_type(): Can only process string or stream arguments", "exception": "ErrorException", "file"

Comment: I have correct the answer. Thank @bhucho for your help.